# Whoosh library, weird behavior of Sequence query with wildcards

Tags: python-3.x, search-engine, whoosh

## Problem

I am trying to implement behaviour similar to sphinx search engine handling phrases with wildcards. For this i use whoosh library. But when i use sequence queries with short words (2 chars length) and wildcards i get an error:

```
    289     return [Span(pos) for pos in self.value_as("positions")]
    290 else:
--> 291     raise Exception("Field does not support spans")

Exception: Field does not support spans
```

I noticied this happens when i add a lot of documents to the index, it doesn't happn with small number of documents though.

I want be able to search with queries like:

- "найденный" AND ("по* мест* проживания" OR "рядом с домом")

Here "по* мест* проживания" causes the error. When i reduce it to "по*" it runs well, if i change it a bit to "по* дороге" i am still getting the same error.

## Code and expected results

```
from whoosh.fields import Schema, TEXT, NUMERIC
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser, PhrasePlugin, SequencePlugin, OperatorsPlugin
from whoosh import analysis
from whoosh.filedb.filestore import RamStorage


analyzer = analysis.StandardAnalyzer(minsize=None, stoplist=None)
schema = Schema(item_id=NUMERIC(stored=True, bits=64), type=NUMERIC(stored=True), content=TEXT(analyzer=analyzer, stored=True, phrase=True))
storage = RamStorage()

    
ix = storage.create_index(schema)
writer = ix.writer()

with get_db() as db:
    for item in db["items"][0:500]:
        writer.add_document(
            item_id=item["id"], type=item["type"], content=item["content"]
        )
writer.commit(optimize=True)




parser = QueryParser("content", schema=schema)
op = OperatorsPlugin(
    And="AND", Or="OR", AndNot="ANT", Not=None, AndMaybe=None, Require=None
)
parser.remove_plugin_class(PhrasePlugin)
parser.add_plugin(SequencePlugin())
parser.replace_plugin(op)


with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    query = '"найденный" AND ("по* мест* проживания" OR "рядом с домом")'
    query = parser.parse(query, debug=True)
    hits = searcher.search(query, terms=True, limit=None)
    pprint(list(hits))
```

Expecting to get a list of hits but I am getting the *Exception: Field does not support spans* instead.

My content is text of variable length in different languages. Queries are also might be in different languages.